# Determine if Activity is called by a Notification

Tags: android, notifications, android-pendingintent

I am using an **Activitiy** with various **Tabs** on it. From a different part of the application, Notifications are created to tell the user that something has changed. I now managed to Call the **Activity**, when the user clicks on the **Notification**. But how can i determine wheter a **Activity** is created the "normal" way during runtime or by clicking on the notification?

(Depending on the notification clicked, i want to forward to another tab instead of showing the main Tab.)

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ctx, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctx, 0, intent, 0);

        // TODO: Replace with .Build() for api >= 16
        Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(ctx)
                .setContentTitle("Notification"
                .setContentText(this.getName())
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setDefaults(
                        Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND
                                | Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .getNotification();

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) ctx
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        // Hide the notification after its selected
        notificationManager.notify(this.getId(), noti);
```

This successfully calls my MainActivity. But is there some Method that is called when the Activity is triggered by the `pendingIntent`?

Thought about to define something like this in the **Main Activity**:

```
onTriggeredByNotification(Notification noti){
     //determinte tab, depending on Notification.
}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Pass a boolean value from notification and check for the same in the onCreate method of the activity.

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(ctx, MainActivity.class);
 intent.putExtra("fromNotification", true);
```

...

```
if (getIntent().getExtras() != null) {
  Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
  boolean cameFromNotification = b.getBoolean("fromNotification");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this in your **Notification**

```
Intent intent=new Intent();
intent.setAction("Activity1");
```

In the **Activity** override `onNewIntent()` method and get action so you can determine the activity is called or not.

Comment: I tried that, but the `onNewIntent` Method is not triggered at any Time.

Comment: Ok then try to get the intent in onCreate() of activity.

Answer (score 1):

Better than using the reserved action field of your intent as specified by @ricintech, you could use an extra parameter in your pending intent and detect it in your `onCreate` method and in your `onNewIntent` metod inside your activity.

Answer (score 0):

Add `android:launchMode="singleTop"` in manifest file ,then only `onNewIntent()` will get call