# How to check if Activity has started from notification in Android?

Tags: android, android-activity, notifications

I am making an Android app. I have problem, that is,  My MainActivity can be created by 3 ways:

1. standard app launch
2. from Service
3. and from notification click.

How I can check when it starts from notification click?

Notification code:

```
private void createNotification()
{
    Log.d("service createNotification",MainActivity.TAG);
    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(AppNames.IS_NOTIFICATION_INTENT,true);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
            notificationIntent, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setContentTitle(this.getString(R.string.notification_title))
            .setContentText(this.getString(R.string.notification_text))             
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)             
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

    getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(AppNames.APP_NOTIFICATION, builder.getNotification());
}
```

Answer (score 8):

add

```
intent.putExtra("started_from","notification");
```

to the code that starts the intent from the notifications, and the same thing to the other startActivity calls just change the value, then inside your activity

```
String startedFrom = getIntent().getStringExtra("started_from");
```

for more refer to this question: [How do I get extra data from intent on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233873/how-to-get-extra-data-from-intent-in-android)

Comment: unfochnately this method does'nt work, It always get notification in all 3 cases.

Comment: you need to change "notification" in putExtra to something else, to "service" for example.

Comment: doesn't work at all, look @http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14122085/determine-if-activity-is-called-by-a-notification if any1 interested

Answer (score 0):

To identify which service or broadcast receiver acts as a notification trampoline in your app, look at the output of the following terminal command:

```
adb shell dumpsys activity service \com.android.systemui/.dump.SystemUIAuxiliaryDumpService
```

output includes the text "NotifInteractionLog". This section contains the information that's necessary to identify the component that starts as the result of a notification tap.